# Exchange mailbox migration to office365 stuck at Syncing/inprogress

Tags: office365, exchange-server

Hello guys, so i am currently migrating our exchange server 2012 to office 365 exchange online using the hybrid connectivity approach (remote move). All pilot users were successfully migrated except this one user who has been stuck at syncing for a very long period of time without any significant activity going on (Data migrated still at 0). I have tried to stop/delete the user using Stop-migrationUser cmdlet and tried to start the migration again using new-MoveRequest and still the same. From powershell moveRequestStatistics of that user, the Status is stuck at *In progress* while the StatusItem is stuck at *WorkItemPickup*. This particular users mailbox seems to be larger than every other user in the initial pilot batch created @*13.31Gb* worth of mailbox size. Please what can i do to re-mediate this? see below migration stats of current problem user/mailbox..

RunspaceId                               : 4b9964c2-cc29-4cdc-9ce5-499bdb0545f1

MailboxIdentity                          : Wonuola Oyeledun

DistinguishedName                        : CN=Wonuola Oyeledun,OU=egbinpower.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange

Hosted Organizations,DC=EURPR10A003,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM

DisplayName                              : Wonuola Oyeledun

Alias                                    : wonuola.oyeledun

ExchangeGuid                             : d90a27ed-4017-486e-a843-09af3214612b

ArchiveGuid                              :

Status                                   : InProgress

StatusDetail                             : WorkItemPickup

SyncStage                                : None

Flags                                    : CrossOrg, Pull

RequestStyle                             : CrossOrg

Direction                                : Pull

IsOffline                                : False

Protect                                  : False

DoNotPreserveMailboxSignature            : True

Priority                                 : Normal

WorkloadType                             : Onboarding

Suspend                                  : False

SuspendWhenReadyToComplete               : False

IgnoreRuleLimitErrors                    : False

RecipientTypeDetails                     : MailUser

SourceVersion                            : Version 15.0 (Build 1367.0)

SourceDatabase                           :

SourceServer                             : EGB032.egbin-power.local

TargetVersion                            : Version 15.20 (Build 2856.0)

TargetDatabase                           : EURPR10DG070-db073

TargetServer                             : HE1PR1001MB1113.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM

SourceArchiveDatabase                    :

SourceArchiveVersion                     :

SourceArchiveServer                      :

TargetArchiveDatabase                    :

TargetArchiveVersion                     :

TargetArchiveServer                      :

RemoteHostName                           : owa.egbin-power.com

RemoteTenant                             :

RemoteGlobalCatalog                      :

BatchName                                : Wonuola_oyeledun

StartAfter                               :

CompleteAfter                            : 12/31/9999 1:00:00 AM

EffectiveIncrementalSyncInterval         : 1.00:00:00

ConfiguredIncrementalSyncInterval        :

RemoteCredentialUsername                 : egbin-power\o365.admin

RemoteDatabase                           : 9c976c93-8f25-4712-a6f2-23bb74aab4bd

RemoteDatabaseName                       : EG_Dbase1B

RemoteArchiveDatabase                    :

RemoteArchiveDatabaseName                :

TargetDeliveryDomain                     : egbinpower.mail.onmicrosoft.com

ArchiveDomain                            : egbinpower.mail.onmicrosoft.com

BadItemLimit                             : 500

RetryCleanup                             : False

BadItemsEncountered                      : 0

LargeItemLimit                           : 100

LargeItemsEncountered                    : 0

AllowLargeItems                          : False

DataConsistencyScore                     :

QueuedTimestamp                          : 3/29/2020 10:54:10 PM

StartTimestamp                           :

LastUpdateTimestamp                      : 3/30/2020 4:42:49 AM

LastSuccessfulSyncTimestamp              :

InitialSeedingCompletedTimestamp         :

FinalSyncTimestamp                       :

CompletionTimestamp                      :

SuspendedTimestamp                       :

OverallDuration                          : 08:35:55.8622131

TotalSuspendedDuration                   : 00:00:00

TotalFailedDuration                      : 00:00:00

TotalQueuedDuration                      : 00:00:14.3613461

TotalInProgressDuration                  : 08:35:04.9331586

TotalStalledDueToContentIndexingDuration : 00:00:00

TotalStalledDueToMdbReplicationDuration  : 00:00:00

TotalStalledDueToMailboxLockedDuration   : 00:00:00

TotalStalledDueToReadThrottle            : 00:00:00

TotalStalledDueToWriteThrottle           : 00:00:00

TotalStalledDueToReadCpu                 : 00:00:00

TotalStalledDueToWriteCpu                : 00:00:00

TotalStalledDueToReadUnknown             : 00:00:00

TotalStalledDueToWriteUnknown            : 00:00:00

TotalTransientFailureDuration            : 00:00:36.5677084

MRSServerName                            : HE1PR1001MB1113.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM

TotalMailboxSize                         : 13.31 GB (14,286,756,692 bytes)

TotalMailboxItemCount                    : 92203

TotalArchiveSize                         :

TotalArchiveItemCount                    :

TotalPrimarySize                         : 13.31 GB (14,286,756,692 bytes)

TotalPrimaryItemCount                    : 92203

BytesTransferred                         : 0 B (0 bytes)

BytesTransferredPerMinute                : 0 B (0 bytes)

ItemsTransferred                         : 0

ShardBytesTransferred                    : 0 B (0 bytes)

ShardItemsTransferred                    : 0

ArchiveBytesTransferred                  : 0 B (0 bytes)

ArchiveItemsTransferred                  : 0

PercentComplete                          : 0

CompletedRequestAgeLimit                 : 3650.00:00:00

InternalFlags                            : SkipKnownCorruptions

JobFeatures                              : BinaryJobFeatures, UseRequestGuidForMoveReport, ShardMergeOnboarding

FailureCode                              :

FailureType                              :

FailureSide                              :

Message                                  :

FailureTimestamp                         :

IsValid                                  : True

ValidationMessage                        :

RequestGuid                              : e5b70882-0bc2-4b46-8148-455f8117596e

RequestQueue                             : EURPR10DG070-db073

MigrationMailboxGuid                     :

SourceEndpointGuid                       :

Identity                                 : Wonuola Oyeledun

Report                                   :

OutOfSlaConditions                       : {}

LastFailure                              :

RequestExpiryTimestamp                   : 3/29/2022 9:54:10 PM

CanSetRetryingStatus                     : False

RemoveRequestWhenCorrupt                 : False

IsContinousJob                           : False

IsSyncAggregation                        : False

IsShadowSync                             : False

CloudCacheAccountType                    : None

Diagnostics                              :

DiagnosticInfo                           :

ObjectState